# Add sort to the linq

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have the below code :

```
lclFullsys = "10090807060504030201"

lclFullSys = "[" & string.Join(",", lclFullSys.Select(Function (x, n) New With { x, n }).GroupBy(Function (x) x.n \ 2, Function (x) x.x).Select(Function (y) New String(y.ToArray()))) & "]"
```

that produces the below string

```
[10,09,08,07,06,05,04,03,02,01]
```

I would like to add a sort to obtain the below string:

```
[01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### EDIT

I saw you edited your post so i'll edit my answer too. I just changed the content of `lclFullSys` to match your input and get the result you wanted :

**C#** :

```
string lclFullsys = "[10,09,08,07,06,05,04,03,02,01]";
var orderedChars =
    (from c in lclFullsys.Replace("[", "")
                         .Replace("]", "")
                         .Split(',')
        orderby int.Parse(c)
        select int.Parse(c).ToString("00")).ToArray();
string result = "[" + string.Join(",", orderedChars) + "]";
```

**VB.NET** :

```
Dim lclFullsys As String = "[10,09,08,07,06,05,04,03,02,01]"
Dim orderedChars = (From c In lclFullsys.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "").Split(","c) Order By Integer.Parse(c) Select Integer.Parse(c).ToString("00")).ToArray()
Dim result As String = "[" & String.Join(",", orderedChars) & "]"
```

Output : `"[01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10]"`

Note : C# code is converted to VB.NET with the [Telerik code converter](https://converter.telerik.com/) so I hope it will work in VB.NET too.

Comment: I edited my answer again to match your needs. Please consider accepting the answer if it's correct for you, cheers !

Answer (score 0):

The magic function `.OrderBy(Function(x) x)` where `x` is the parameter (As `String` in your case) and the function return a `OrderedEnumerable` by that parameter.

```
lclFullsys = "[" & String.Join(",", lclFullsys.Select(Function(x, n) New With {x, n}).GroupBy(Function(x) x.n \ 2, Function(x) x.x).Select(Function(y) New String(y.ToArray())).OrderBy(Function(x) x)) & "]"
```

Comment: Congratulations! Broke 1,000.

Comment: @Mary Thank you. I missed you these days. I hope everything OK from you. To the next ;), Stay safe.